# Prevent application from using all IPs on port (0.0.0.0:34964)

Tags: raspberry-pi, network-interface, port-forwarding, network-namespaces

I have two applications that use the same port for network communication (34964). I have control over (source code) the first application and it uses 192.168.0.4:34964. Whereas the other application tries to use/"claim" all IP addresses (0.0.0.0:34964), but this one I have no control over. Each application works running alone, however when I try to make them run at the same time I get an error: Failed to bind address.

**Question**

Is there any way to prevent the second application from using/claiming all IP addresses (0.0.0.0) and instead use 192.168.0.5. Either before starting it, or by encapsulating it in a network namespace?

I have tried nothing and I am all out of ideas...

**More detailed version:**
Two application to communicate on two separate Profinet networks. The first application acts as a Profinet device and communicates with a Siemens Profinet controller, I have access to the source code to this application. The second application should act as a Profinet Controller that talks to a Profinet Siemens device, I am currently using Codesys for this and have no access to change the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

### LD_PRELOAD

You could use an `LD_PRELOAD` library to intercept the `bind()` system call to force binding to a specific address.  One example of that is [this](http://www.ryde.net/code/bind.c.txt), which you compile like this:

```
gcc -nostartfiles -fpic -shared bind.c -o bind.so -ldl -D_GNU_SOURCE
```

And use like this:

```
BIND_ADDR=127.0.0.1 LD_PRELOAD=./bind.so /path/to/myprogram
```

### Network namespaces w/ Docker

You could also elect to run your program inside its own network namespace.  The *easiest* way to do this would be to build a Docker image for your application and then run it under Docker, and use Docker's port mapping capabilities to expose the service on the host ip of your choice.

### Here there be dragons

I would strongly recommend one of the above solutions. I only include the following because you asked about network namespaces.

### Network namespaces w/ macvlan

If you want to do it without Docker it's possible but a little more work.  First, create a new network namespace:

```
# ip netns add myns
```

Then create a `macvlan` interface associated with one of your host interfaces and put it into the namespace:

```
# ip link add myiface link eth0 type macvlan mode bridge
# ip link set myiface netns myns
```

And assign it an address on your local network:

```
# ip netns exec myns \
  ip addr add 192.168.0.4/24 dev myiface
# ip netns exec myns \
  ip link set myiface up
```

And create appropriate routing rules inside the namespace (substituting your actual gateway address for `192.168.0.1`):

```
# ip netns exec myns \
  ip route add default via 192.168.0.1
```

Now, run your program inside the network namespace:

```
# ip netns exec myns \
  /path/to/myprogram
```

Now your program is running and will bind only to `192.168.0.4`, because that is the only address visible inside the namespace.  But! Be aware of the limitation of `mavclan` interfaces: while other hosts on your network will be able to connect to the service, you will not be able to connect to that address from the host on which it is running (unless you create another `macvlan` interface on the host and route connections to `192.168.0.4` via that interface).

### Network namespaces w/ veth interfaces

Instead of using `macvlan` interfaces, you can create a `veth` interface pair, with one end of the pair inside a network namespace and the other on your host.  You will use ip masquerading to pass packets from the namespace to your local network.

Create the network namespace:

```
# ip netns add myns
```

Create an interface pair:

```
# ip link add myiface-in type veth peer name myiface-out
```

Assign one end of the pair to your network namespace:

```
# ip link setns myiface-in myns
```

Configure an address on each end of the pair and bring up the links:

```
# ip addr add 192.168.99.1/24 dev myiface-out
# ip link set myiface-out up
# ip netns exec myns ip addr add 192.168.99.2/24 dev myiface-in
# ip netns exec myns ip link set myiface-in up
```

Configure ip masquerading on your host.  This will redirect incoming packets on `192.168.0.4` to your namespace:

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.4 -p tcp --dport 34964 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.99.2
# iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.4 -p tcp --dport 34964 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.99.2
```

And this will masquerade outbound packets:

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.99.2 -j MASQUERADE
```

You will need to ensure that you have ip forwarding enabled on your host (`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`) and that your iptables `FORWARD` chain permits forwarding the connection (`iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.99.2 -j ACCEPT`, keeping in mind that rules are processed in sequence so a reject rule *before* this one will take precedence).