# How to Make a Systemd Private Network Namespace Accessable

Tags: ssh, networking, systemd, socket, namespace

So I have an application that only binds to `0.0.0.0` and listens on a port (TCP).
The communication is unencrypted and unauthorized so I'd like to work around that without getting too deep into the weeds.

I'd like it to bind on `127.0.0.1` so I can do the [SSH Forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280827/can-someone-explain-ssh-tunnel-in-a-simple-way) Trick to get auth and encryption.

Still the problem remains that the process is bound to `0.0.0.0` and accessible from the outside.

One Idea I had was using Systemd's [`PrivateNetwork`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#JoinsNamespaceOf=) to isolate the network (I want to sandbox the application in other ways too) but I don't know how to then get the SSH forward working.
Maybe running a `sshd` and [joining](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#JoinsNamespaceOf=) the network namespace?
But then how do I get the joined `sshd` accessible from "outside"?

Is there an easier way then getting [LD_PRELOAD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356337/prevent-application-from-using-all-ips-on-port-0-0-0-034964) involved or doing [socket](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/637159/network-namespace-slirp4netns-access-namespaced-network-from-host) shenanigans? Preferably involving `systemd` units/service in some way like [this socat answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/298409/547767).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first off: A network application that binds to 0.0.0.0 and is not configurable would count as fatally bugged in my book, and if you have any leverage, that would be something the developer would need to fix. (As a FOSS maintainer/developer, this is never a problem: worst case, that's a one-line fix you can do yourself.)

An option you could also consider is the `LD_PRELOAD` trick, where you just preload a really tiny library that hijacks `libc`'s `bind` call, checks it for binding a TCP socket to 0.0.0.0, and bends the actual call to the actual `bind` function so that it binds to the address of your choosing.

Easier, even, is just dropping a firewall rule on the public interface(s) that forbids connecting to the port, so that only loopback connections work.

The highly-encapsulating way of solving this, and probably a reduction of migration/maintenance work later on, would be to put your application in a Linux container (e.g. as run by `podman`), and just publish the port internally. (You can very nicely use `podman generate` to generate systemd unit files for such containers and their infrastructure to be started automatically, and you can even run these things without special privileges, which can be a security advantage over what this frankly not-greatly-written network application does right now.)

The almighty, nothing-leaves-this-machine-unencrypted solution might be what is described in the [wireguard manual](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/#the-new-namespace-solution), where you literally take the physical interfaces your computer has away from all the programs running in the default namespace, push them into a separate namespace, and only allow an VPN tunnel connection (a wireguard interface) to interact with these. Not your SSH solution, but if wireguard fits your scenario, that might be an option.

> One Idea I had was using Systemd's PrivateNetwork to isolate the network (I want to sandbox the application in other ways too) but I don't know how to then get the SSH forward working.

That *is* a nice approach! Sadly I think `PrivateNetwork=` very successfully isolates *all* network in that namespace, and you'd have to write a program that somehow extract the ephemeral network NS name, and hands it to another unit that will then set up a bridge (typically: an macvlan `ip link` construct) and transfers it into that namespace. A bit of an overhead.

You could instead have a setup where you have

1. a one-shot unit that uses `ip` to create a namespace, sets up the `lo` device inside, and binds the new namespace to itself. Then,
2. you have your questionable service use `NetworkNamespacePath=` to be in that namespace;
3. you add a bridge into that namespace in another one-shot unit

There's an [article I found](https://www.cloudnull.io/2019/04/running-services-in-network-name-spaces-with-systemd/) which describes pretty much that.

---

Conclusion: I think this is easiest with a single `iptables`/`nftables` rule, but if you need to set up bridged namespaces, that should be possible. You're, however, darn close to the use case that people usually just throw containers at, and this might be the most flexible solution.

Comment: It's USB/IP so yeah I guess it's within my power to change the bind code.
Did consider the container approach, probably what I'll go with anyway, more transportable then faffing with systemd.
Thinking on it, unsure why I was opposed to `LD_PRELOAD` it's pretty simple and slots into a service file simply.
Didn't think to do that with Wiregaurd! Little intense for what I want to do with it tho, but I do need to learn WG sometime.
nftables is the shortest approach. Thanks.

Comment: yeah the "put all physical NICs into a namespace" approach from the wireguard website is quite a handful, and probably not what you want if your network configuration is somewhat dynamic. But wireguard in itself is super simple; you just need one side with a known IP address, you run a simple command to generate public and private keys for both ends of a tunnel, and then you use these. Honestly, lowest-hassle tunneling I had to deal with so far.

Comment: Coming from OVPN, hard agree.
It's just the "sitting down with it for a week" that's hard right now.

Comment: @WesAtWork the usual!